# C++ Typecast int pointer to void pointer to char pointer?

Tags: c++

Hello im confused by typecasting pointers.
I understand that void can hold any type.

So if i have an int * with a value inside of it then i make a void * to the int * can i then typecast it to a char?

It's quite hard to explain what i mean and the title might be wrong but will this work?

And is it safe to do this. I've seen it used quite alot in C. Is this bad practise.

```
int main() {
    int* a = new int{ 65 };
    void* v = static_cast<int*>(a);
    std::cout << *(static_cast<char *>(v));
}
```

Comment: It was all well until `cout <<`. When you pass a `char*` to it, it must point into a null-terminated character array. If what you have in that place is an `int`, it may or may not contain any zero bytes in it. But why do you want to do this? The cose as shown doesn't make a lot of sense.

Comment: You can use `reinterpret_cast`.

Comment: The first comment is missing the fact that you're dereferencing the `char*`, and so it does _not_ need to point at a string. However, the "why do you want to do this" question is still valid. Perhaps this is just a toy example to demonstrate a real-world issue where you receive a `void*` from somewhere and you need to access its bytes. But sometimes examples like this are motivated by crazy notions. So it's useful to know precisely what you want to achieve in case you're going about it completely wrong.

Comment: Not trying to use it for anything i was just on a chapter that talked about it on learncpp is all so i was trying to understand it.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> I understand that void can hold any type.

You understand it wrong. Pointer does not hold data, it points to it. So integer pointer points to memory with holds integer, float pointer points where float is etc. Void pointer just points to some memory, but it says - I do not know what kind of data is there.

Now conversion. Technically you can convert almost any pointer to any  (there are exceptions like function pointers or pointers to a member, but they are completely different beasts and it is not what you are asking about) as they all just pointers. But problem happens when you try to access memory where they point to. So if you have `int` in memory and try to read it as `float` or vice versa - that's illegal. Now therte is one exception - you can access any data through pointer to `char` (or `unsigned char`) as `char` represents `byte`. Void pointer is irrelevant here, you can convert from pointer of one type to another without `void *` involved:

```
int main() {
    int* a = new int{ 65 };
    unsigned char *uptr = reinterpret_cast<unsigned char *>( a );
    for( size_t i = 0; i < sizeof(int); ++i )
        std::cout << static_cast<unsigned int>( uptr[i] ) << ' ';
}
```

[Live example](https://ideone.com/uxX4bp)

Note I casted `uptr[i]` to unsigned int, that is to print bytes as numbers, as C++ stream ( `std::cout` in this case) will print character as symbol, which would be meaningless in this case.

Comment: "Technically you can convert any pointer " --> conversion `void*` to/from function pointers is not certainly supported - even their sizes may differ.  `void *` to/from an _object_ pointer is.

Answer (score 1):

First any object pointer can be cast to `void*`. That's the generic "could be anything" solution inherited from C and you should not use it. The C++ way is to use `template<typename T>` and `T*` for such cases where you need an anything pointer.

Secondly any object pointer can also be cast to `char *` as a special case. Casting to `char*` gives you access to the memory representation of the object. It does not convert the object to a char or anything, you get access to the raw bits for the value stored in the object.

So the reason why casting to `void*` and then to `char*` works is that casting any object pointer to `char*` is valid. The intermediate step to `void*` is not needed at all.

This only works for `char*` or `unsigned char*` or any other *variant of `char`* pointer, including `std::byte*`. You can not static_cast an `int*` to `float*` for example and using a `void*` and intermediate step will not make that work either.

Note: The value printed by the code is implementation defined since the memory representation of an int and a char is defined by the implementation. Specifically their endianness and size of an int and the signedness of char. Apart from that it perfectly valid code.

The question though is: Why do you want to do this?